# Chrome - View source option faded out

Tags: google-chrome, source-code

Ctrl+U doesn't work and the 'view source' option is faded out...

http://geobeck.tripod.com/bin/counter/~geobeck/jokehold/jokes.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the URL is returning a PNG. Here's the output of HttpFox in Firefox:

[image]

Note the Type column.

Also:

```
$ curl -D headers 'http://geobeck.tripod.com/bin/counter/~geobeck/jokehold/jokes.html' >jokes
$ cat headers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Oct 2015 16:50:25 GMT
Server: Squeegit/1.2.5 (3_sir)
Set-Cookie: CookieStatus=COOKIE_OK; path=/; domain=.tripod.com; expires=Sun, 30-Oct-2016 16:50:25 GMT
Vary: *
X-Server-IP: 209.202.244.196
P3P: policyref="http://www.lycos.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa CUSa PSAa IVAa CONo OUR IND UNI STA"
Content-Length: 150
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:16:40 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/png
```

Note the Content-Type header.

```
$ file jokes
jokes: PNG image, 70 x 11, 1-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

PNGs don't have "source", at least in the way a browser allows Viewing Source.